# Iconv, posted data and simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, iconv

So I am using `simplexml_load_string` on some posted XML. However I get the below error.

`Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 8: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xA3 0x37 0x30 0x30 in map_view.php on line 7`

The page is encoded in UTF8. I think it may be the pound sign?
I would `iconv` it yet dont know the current encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<documentContent>
  <property>
    <pic1 hiresURL="http://dmqa.briefyourmarket.com/management/house-sample.jpg" imgpath="http://dmqa.briefyourmarket.com/management/house-sample.jpg" />
    <postCode>de560db</postCode>
    <address>Chilly Road, Bingley, Oxon, OX17</address>
    <postcode>OX17 2HE</postcode>
    <price>£700,000</price>
  </property>
</documentContent>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load XML with PHP when it fails with Input is not proper UTF-8 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354263/how-to-load-xml-with-php-when-it-fails-with-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pound sign is `0xC2 0xA3` in UTF-8; the bytes reported in the error message are the ISO-8859-1 characters: <kbd>£</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, so I think your document is *in fact* encoded as ISO-8859-1 despite the declaration which indicates UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bytes I'd suspect the actual encoding is ISO-8859-1 a.k.a. Latin-1. This should fix it:

```
iconv('ISO-8859-1' ,'UTF-8', $xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sure that the file is UTF-8 encoded? `0xA3` is the byte used to encode the `£` symbol in `ISO-8859-1`. The `£` should be `0xC2 0xA3` in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You've to convert your document into UTF-8, the easiest would be to use [utf8_encode($data)](http://php.net/utf8_encode).

For example:

```
$xmlInput = simplexml_load_string (utf8_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
```

If you don't know the current encoding, use [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding), e.g.:

```
$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url_or_file));
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content);
$doc = new DOMdocument();
$res = $doc->loadXML("<?xml encoding='$encoding'>" . $content);
```

Using DOMDocument it should be like:

```
$td->nodeValue = utf8_encode("&pound;");
```