# How to fix saveHTML(): output conversion failed due to conv error?

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument

Simple code that should work on any url (from my opinion) :

I cannot figure why do i get the following Warning. Any idea ?

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::saveHTML(): output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xE9 0x74 0xC3 0xA9 in ********.php on line 9

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.ludibay.net/');
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content);
$doc = new DomDocument();

$res = @$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="'.$encoding.'">'.$content);
//some treatment on nodes here
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: What happens if you actually _tell_ DOMDocument what it is? (`$doc = new DomDocument('1.0',$encoding);`)

Comment: And use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` instead of `@` ?

Comment: detected encoding is utf-8, when i add as you propose Wrikken, no change of behavior

Comment: Also, see the results from `var_dump(mb_detect_order());`... if your desired character set is not in there... `mb_detect_order()` will not help you much (it's a.... irritating function IMHO, although you can give it limited set of your own making).

Comment: And the actual document seems to be `iso-8859-1` btw...

Comment: Try forcing the UTF8 encoding by `$content=utf8_encode($content)` - this is almost certainly an encoding issue.

Comment: when i set libxml_use_internal_errors(true), no error is returned, but treatment of the output stops on a first unexpected character

Comment: Quickly tested: if you just do: `$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://..');`, the character encoding is detected successfully.

Comment: The problem seems to be the XML tag you're adding

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it helped me. removing my XML tag solved the problem. I will hope it will not make raise problems elsewhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load XML with PHP when it fails with Input is not proper UTF-8 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354263/how-to-load-xml-with-php-when-it-fails-with-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-error)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to force [UTF-8 encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), which converts from iso-8859-1 to UTF-8?  I had a similar issue just now, and it worked for me.  Maybe try:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.ludibay.net/');
$content = utf8_encode($content); // convert $content to utf_8
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content);
$doc = new DomDocument();

$res = @$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="'.$encoding.'">'.$content);
//some treatment on nodes here
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: No need to use `mb_detect_encoding` after `utf8_encode`, since you just forced the encoding to `utf-8`. Also, you mentioned as well, but this only works if `$content` is encoded in `iso-8859-1`.