# Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xF8 0x72 0x72 0x65

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I get the error that i wrote in title.

The line that generates the error says this

```
$properties->asXML("$filename.xml");
```

Despite that i use this string to initialize the object

```
$properties = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><properties/>');
```

Then it outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
```

Why does it change encoding tag ?

Comment: Could not reproduce on my PHP 5.3.10/5.4.12

Comment: Are you putting `ørre` somewhere in there as html-entities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument conv error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194003/php-domdocument-conv-error)